# Tool to monitor SD-Card health

Tags: sd-card, monitoring

A big problem with my always on Raspberry Pi is that every one to two years the SD card gets broken and must be replaced.

Due to many write operations, the wear leveling is running out of spare blocks. Thankfully, the SD card goes to a write only mode, so all the data on it is intact but the Pi stops working. I have to copy the content of the card to a new one and all is running again.

I wonder if there is any way to monitor the health of the SD card to predict when it will fail. Something like `smartctl` for SD cards. It might be vendor specific. Optimum would be to see the number of remaining spare blocks.

Tools like `fsck` will now work because the file system is fully operational until the SD card fails.

Comment: You could set up your system to run from RAID; monitoring the RAID will tell you when one of the sides failed. https://siking.wordpress.com/2017/01/18/raspbian-running-the-system-from-raid/

Answer (score 2):

Nope - they just go read-only if you are lucky and die if you are not.

Best thing you can do is go for a read-only OS or the newer files systems.  Note the standard Raspberry Pi file system may not be the best for heavy writes with stable systems...

- EXT2 helps as there is no journalling but more fragile
- EXT4 has journalling (so more writes) but is designed to help SD card life
  with delayed writes

You could try f2fs (Flash Friendly File System) - this [blog post](https://movr0.com/2016/08/19/convert-raspberry-pi-123-to-f2fs/) has some notes but they are from 2016

Classic delaying tactics are:

- Turn logging off
- Use tmpfs when ever possible
- Restrict writes to bare minimum
- Use another RAM based OS (e.g. [Tiny Core Linux](http://www.tinycorelinux.net))
- Buy decent named cards
- Make them larger than you need (so you have more 'spare' cells)
- Buy A1 style cards - these are designed for applications in 'phones (though not OS level use)
- Look to move to a SSD or HD ASAP
- Build in regular maintenance for changing cards
- Have good backups

To be honest - its a bit overhyped - I've had SD cards in cameras for years with thousands of pictures going on and off them with very little issue.  I still keep good backups though...

*Requesting close as this is not a Pi issue - its an SD Card one as it happens to cameras etc.*

Comment: is there a way to see how many of these 'spare' cells have been allocated?